# Python - Pandas Module - Filter to show as string and NOT boolean

Tags: python, pandas

I have starting to use pandas module, and i am trying to use filter on a column to find a piece of text. I am using the below syntax, and while this works to some degree, this is showing if there is a match and returning a boolean value of true or false.

**Example Input Data**

[image]

**Syntax**

```
test = data["Date"].str.contains("Tue 02 Feb 2021")
print(test)
```

**Example Output Data**

[image]

I would like this to filter and only show text which i have put into the syntax as below:

[image]

Could anybody please shed some light on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```py
test = data[data["Date"].str.contains("Tue 02 Feb 2021")]
```

or:

```py
test = data[data["Date"] =="Tue 02 Feb 2021"]
```

Comment: tested, and this works. Thanks a lot! 

Could i please ask, how would i get this to save when exporting into an excel document? for example, when i have use the rename syntax, to keep this saved in the dataframe i have used inplace = True

How would i go about using that type of feature for this syntax?

Comment: I am not sure if I got your point but do you want to save this subset "test" then in an excel?

Comment: for this https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html is perfect: